# How to group_by and then summarise which rows have NA in all columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure if this is possible.  I want to be able to use summarise to count all the rows that have NA in all the columns besides the group_by.  I am able to do it by putting all 5 conditions together where I have `NO_OL_Percent =` then have to connect each column with `&`.  If you can do it in SQL I should think you could do it with dplyr or purrr but seems like noone on the internet has tried this.

Data must be downloaded [here](https://www.ams.usda.gov/local-food-directories/farmersmarkets)

Code is below.  It works but is there really not a way to use an all function for last row of code?  I need to be able to do a group_by first and I cannot use the filter_all in dplyr.

```
farmers_market = read.csv("Export.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings=c("NA","NaN", ""))

farmers_market %>% 
        select(c("Website", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Youtube", "OtherMedia", "State")) %>%
        group_by(State) %>%
        summarise(Num_Markets = n(),
                  FB_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Facebook))/n(), 
                  TW_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Twitter))/n(),
                  #fb=sum(is.na(Facebook)),
                  OL_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Facebook) & is.na(Twitter))/n(),
                  NO_OL_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Facebook) & is.na(Twitter) & is.na(Website) & is.na(Youtube) & is.na(OtherMedia))/n()
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `select` statement since we are summarising, only relevant columns will be selected anyway. Created a `cols` vector from where we want to calculate `NA`s.

We first check for every row if that row has all `NA` values in `cols` columns and assign `TRUE`/`FALSE` value to new column `all_NA`. We then `group_by` `State` and perform the calculation for rest of columns as it is but for `NO_OL_Percent` we sum `ALL_NA` to get total number of `NA`s per group and divide it to total number of rows in group.

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("Website", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Youtube", "OtherMedia")

farmers_market %>% 
   mutate(all_NA = rowSums(is.na(.[cols])) == length(cols)) %>%
   group_by(State) %>%
   summarise(Num_Markets = n(),
             FB_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Facebook))/n(), 
             TW_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Twitter))/n(),
             OL_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(is.na(Facebook) & is.na(Twitter))/n(),
             NO_OL_Percent = 100 - 100*sum(all_NA)/n())


#    State                Num_Markets FB_Percent TW_Percent OL_Percent NO_OL_Percent
#    <chr>                      <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 Alabama                      139       25.9       5.76       25.9          37.4
# 2 Alaska                        38       42.1      10.5        42.1          65.8
# 3 Arizona                       92       57.6      27.2        57.6          80.4
# 4 Arkansas                     111       52.3       4.50       52.3          61.3
# 5 California                   759       41.5      14.5        43.2          70.1
# 6 Colorado                     161       44.1       9.94       44.1          82.6
# 7 Connecticut                  157       33.8      12.1        33.8          53.5
# 8 Delaware                      36       61.1      11.1        61.1          83.3
# 9 District of Columbia          57       50.9      43.9        50.9          87.7
#10 Florida                      262       43.1       8.78       43.1          83.2
# … with 43 more rows
```

This gives the same output as your current approach but without manually writing all names.

Answer (score 0):

A straight way to get the `Percent` column would be:

```
farmers_market %>% 
    select("Website", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Youtube", "OtherMedia", "State") %>%
    group_by(State) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs("Percent" = sum(is.na(.))/n()))

# A tibble: 53 x 6
#  State   Website_Percent Facebook_Percent Twitter_Percent Youtube_Percent OtherMedia_Percent
#  <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl>
#1 Alabama           0.727            0.741           0.942           0.993              0.964
#2 Alaska            0.447            0.579           0.895           1                  0.974
```

To add the `num_markets` column, an option is do this:

```
farmers_market %>% 
    select("Website", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Youtube", "OtherMedia", "State") %>%
    group_by(State) %>% 
    mutate(num_markets = n()) %>% 
    group_by(State, num_markets) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs("Percent" = sum(is.na(.))/n()))

# A tibble: 53 x 7
# Groups:   State [2]
#  State   num_markets Website_Percent Facebook_Percent Twitter_Percent Youtube_Percent OtherMedia_Percent
#  <chr>         <int>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl>
#1 Alabama         139           0.727            0.741           0.942           0.993              0.964
#2 Alaska           38           0.447            0.579           0.895           1                  0.974
```